# What is the terminal electron acceptor in methanogenesis?

Tags: anaerobic-respiration

I learnt that methanogenesis is a type of anaerobic respiration that utilizes carbon compounds such as CO2 or acetic acid as their terminal electron acceptor in their electron transport chain rather than using oxygen. However, when I went through my textbook, I found out that conversion of CO2 to CH4 is not one step reaction but many other compounds are synthesized in between and methyl-SCoM is converted to methane.In one article I read that Com-SH is the terminal acceptor When I tried searching in google for the same I came across a lot of diagrams of mechanism but some of them did not match with each other. I have no idea what's going on. It would be really helpful if you can help me out here.